# SSH-less LXC containers using Ansible

Tags: ansible, lxc

I am new to ansible, and I am trying to use ansible on some lxc containers.
My problem is that I don't want to install ssh on my containers. So

What I tried:

I tried to use this connection [plugin](https://github.com/chifflier/ansible-lxc-ssh) but it seams that it does not work with ansible 2.
After understanding that chifflier connection plugin doesn't work, I tried to use the connection plugin from [openstack](https://github.com/openstack/openstack-ansible-plugins/blob/master/connection/ssh.py).

After some failed attempts I dived into the code, and I understand
that the plugin doesn't have the information that the host I am talking with is a container.(because the code never reached this [point](https://github.com/openstack/openstack-ansible-plugins/blob/master/connection/ssh.py#L128))

My current setup:
{Ansbile host}---|ssh|---{vm}--|ansible connection plugin|---{container1}

My ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
connection_plugins = /home/jkarr/ansible-test/connection_plugins/ssh
inventory = inventory
```

My inventory:

```
[hosts]
vm ansible_host=192.168.28.12

[containers]
mailserver physical_host=vm container_name=mailserver
```

my group vars:

```
ansible_host: "{{ physical_hostname }}"
ansible_ssh_extra_args: "{{ container_name }}"
ansible_user: containeruser
container_name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
physical_hostname: "{{ hostvars[physical_host]['ansible_host'] }}"
```

My testing playbook:

```
- name: Test Playbook
  hosts: containers
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: testfile
      copy:
        content: "Test"
        dest: /tmp/test
```

The output is:

```
fatal: [mailserver]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname mailserver: No address associated with hostname\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Ansible version is: 2.3.1.0

So what am I doing wrong? any tips?
Thanks in advance!

**Update 1:**
Based on [eric answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45151276/1040155) I am now using this connection [plug-in](https://github.com/Mic92/ansible-lxc).
I update the my inventory and it looks like:

```
[hosts]
vm ansible_host=192.168.28.12

[containers]
mailserver physical_host=vm ansible_connection=lxc
```

After running my playbook I took:

```
<192.168.28.12> THIS IS A LOCAL LXC DIR
fatal: [mailserver]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "192.168.28.12 is not running"
}
```

Which is weird because 192.168.28.12 is the vm and the container is called mailserver. Also I verified that the container is running.

Also why it says that 192.168.28.12 is local lxc dir?

**Update 2:**

I remove my group_vars, my ansible.cfg and the connection plugin from the playbook and I got the this error:

```
<mailserver> THIS IS A LOCAL LXC DIR
fatal: [mailserver]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "mailserver is not running"
}
```

Comment: The error says that the host mailserver is not assigned an IP in the Ansible inventory file. Can you set the IP  for the host and try again ?

Comment: @Tejaswi I tried to change 'mailserver' to the assigned IP of the container but I got the same error.

Comment: @jkarr Your `group_vars` are overriding `ansible_host `. Can you try a simple `debug` with no `group_vars`?

Comment: @EricCitaire after removing group_vars, connection_plugin folder and ansible.cfg, I got similar error see updated question.

Comment: Have you tried adding `container_name=mailserver`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should take a look at this [lxc connection plugin](https://github.com/Mic92/ansible-lxc). It might fit your needs.

**Edit :** [`lxc`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commits/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/connection/lxc.py) connection plugin is actually part of Ansible.

Just add `ansible_connection=lxc` in your inventory or group vars.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the connection plugin you recommend got me a bit further. See the update 1 in my question for more info to my 'new problem'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying something similar.

I want to configure a host over ssh using ansible and run lxc containers on the host, which are also configured using ansible:

```
ansible control node ----> host-a -----------> container-a
                      ssh          lxc-attach
```

The issue with the `lxc` connection module is, that it only works for local lxc containers. There is no way to get it working through ssh.

At the moment the only way seems to be a direct ssh connection or a ssh connection through the first host:

```
                      ssh
ansible control node ----> container-a

or
                      ssh          ssh
ansible control node ----> host-a ----> container-a
```

Both require sshd installed in the container. But the second way doesn't need port forwarding or multiple ip addresses.

Did you get a working solution?